# Scratch my last email?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

What does it mean if someone said "scratch my last email"?

Comment: See meaning 6a at [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scratch)

Comment: [***Belay** my earlier email / comment / instructions.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22belay+my+earlier%22)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is similar to "scratch something off the list", i.e. remove, ignore or delete it.

Comment: Correct overall, but to clarify this specific context, it means to ignore whatever was said the last email. You shouldn't delete the email and still do whatever it said.